# Ignore inaccessible sources w/ dotnet add package

Tags: c#, .net-core, nuget, command-line-interface

When I try to add a NuGet package via the `dotnet` cli I get an error that it can't access one of my custom NuGet sources.  Is there a way to say "I don't care, **restore from where you can**"?

[McMaster.Extensions.CommandLineUtils](https://www.nuget.org/packages/McMaster.Extensions.CommandLineUtils) clearly it exists in NuGet.org and it finds it but then stops b/c it can't access a custom source ‍♂️.

> PS c:\Temp\blah-project> dotnet add package McMaster.Extensions.CommandLineUtils
>   info : Adding PackageReference for package 'McMaster.Extensions.CommandLineUtils' into project 'c:\Temp\blah-project\blah-project.csproj'.
>   info : Restoring packages for c:\Temp\blah-project\blah-project.csproj
>   info :   GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/mcmaster.extensions.commandlineutils/index.json
>   info :   OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/mcmaster.extensions.commandlineutils/index.json 147ms
>   error: Unable to load the service index for source https://myinstace.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/Blah/nuget/v3/index.json.
>   error:   Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).

Answer (score 4):

The `dotnet` command has the [option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-restore) to specify `--source`. This allows you to only restore packages from a specific location, in this case you'd want to use

```
dotnet restore --source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
```

This should pull the packages down to your local NuGet store and solve the problem *on your machine.*

In order to add the package to your project you may need to manually add a `<PackageReference>` to your project like

```
<PackageReference Include="McMaster.Extensions.CommandLineUtils" Version="2.6.0" />
```

Then running the restore command above will get the package for you.

As a more-permanent fix, you should put a `nuget.config` file in the root of the project/repository where you specify the package sources for that specific project. There are settings that you can set to override your system's global nuget configuration/sources. See more information on [nuget.config](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-config-file). You can create a starting nuget.config in your repo with `dotnet new nugetconfig`

Answer (score 2):

while restoring packages, dotnet make a call to all the package sources to get the package and uses the one that responds first.

In your case, because of some authentication issue it is not able to access that source. That source can be disabled using the below command and then try to pull the package.

```
dotnet nuget disable source <NAME> [--configfile <FILE>]
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be able use the `--ignore-failed-sources` option.

I'd recently encountered similar issues when having authentication problems on a private feed, this allowed me to install the packages (was actually a tool using `dotnet tool install`) and address my auth issue at a later date.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-restore for more info and options.

Comment: looks like that arg will work for `dotnet restore` but I'm not seeing a similar arg on [dotnet add package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-add-package) unfortunately